# Add multiple instances of a property to a list

Tags: c#, object-oriented, linq

I'm a novice programmer asking first question here although I've gotten tons of help from previous questions.
The following code is abstracted from what I currently have working.

```
List<decimal> teamAverage1 = new List<decimal>();
List<decimal> teamAverage2 = new List<decimal>();
List<decimal> teamAverage3 = new List<decimal>();

foreach (int id in TeamIds)
{
    foreach (Player player in Players.Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.a == 'x'))
    {
        teamAverage1.Add(player.Average1);
    }
    foreach (Player player in Players.Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.b == 'y'))
    {
        teamAverage2.Add(player.Average2);
    }
    foreach (Player player in Players.Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.c == 'z'))
    {
        teamAverage3.Add(player.Average3);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the nested foreach loop and do something like:

```
foreach (int id in TeamIds)
{
    List<decimal> teamAverage1 = Players.Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.a == 'x').Average1
    List<decimal> teamAverage2 = Players.Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.b == 'y').Average2
    List<decimal> teamAverage3 = Players.Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.c == 'z').Average3
}
```

Is there a way to do this and if there is - is it a better solution than the original code?  I have a long list of properties to average and this would be much cleaner than many foreach loops.

More info: TeamIds identify each team.  Each player has teamId to relate it to a team.  Code should iterate every team id, find different subsets of players that belong to that team and add the stats of those players to lists for the team.  Thank you for your help, let me know if still not clear or if I have something wrong.

The linq statements can and will return more than one record.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Much as we would love to review your code, the code snippet is Incomplete for instance What does TeamIds, Players mean? Can you add more description to your post so we can deduce what your code does.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: I posted the actual code

Comment: I rolled your question back because psuedocode is not allowed in CR.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because it is example code. You have tried adding the "actual code" before; if that's really your real code, post it again, but ALSO edit the description to describe what you're really doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with LINQ:

```
var teamAverage1 = new List<decimal>();  
....

foreach (int id in TeamIds)
{
    teamAverage1.AddRange(
        Players.Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.a == 'x').Select(p => p.Average1));

    ...
}
```

Or you can take it one step further and remove the outer loop too:

```
var teamAverage1 = TeamIds
    .SelectMany(id => PlayersPlayers.Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.a == 'x').Select(p => p.Average1))
    .ToList();
```

Check out [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx) for complete list of LINQ queries. Note, that you can also calculate average value itself, using `Average` method:

```
var teamAverageaValue1 = TeamIds
    .SelectMany(id => PlayersPlayers.Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.a == 'x'))
    .Average(p => p.Average1);
```

P.S. This: `p.a == 'x'` smells. I have no idea what this is supposed to mean, but i can guarantee you that you can come up with better property name, than `a` (which should be `PascalCase` btw), and with better property type, than `char`.

Comment: Thank you Nikita B and everyone.  This answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten the first part to 3x this:

```
var teamAverage1 = Players
    .Where(p => p.teamId == id && p.a == 'x')
    .Select(x => x.Average1)
    .ToList();
```

I don't like the `p.a` properties. They look like a bad design. But it's hard to say more from the snippet you've showed.

Answer (score 0):

I am going by your last statement, that you are summing up all stats for the players in a team, and you're doing that for every team.

Are you not looking for something like this:

```
for P in all players:
{
    PlayerStatistics = P.stats
    PlayersTeamID = P.TeamID
    // now add the statistics of this player to his respective team:
    Team[PlayerTeamID].add(PlaterStatistics)
}
```

Or in short:

```
for P in all players:
{
    Team[P.TeamID].add(P.stats)
}
```

This would run through the playertable top to bottom exactly once and collect all the statistics to the respective teams. I do not see a much faster way but then again, it is late.